# How to set numbers in increasing order (Example: 0, 1, 2, 4, 6 to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

Tags: java, android

I have a list like 0,1,2,3. When I delete the number 2 from that list I get 0, 1, 3. How do I do to change the list to 0, 1, 2?

```
holder.closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override public void onClick(View view){
                if(ItemsListAdapter.this.onItemClickListener != null){                  
ItemsList.this.onItemClickListener.onItemCloseBtnClicked(itemModel);
                    ItemRepository.getInstance.delete(itemModel);
                    List<ItemEntity> items = ItemRepository.getInstance().selectAll();
                    if(itemModel.getIndex() > itemModel.size()){
                        for(ItemEntity itemEntity : items){
                            //
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why not just delete the last item in the list, instead of deleting one in the middle and then trying to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody for the help.
But I solved my problem doing something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
  items.get(i).setIndex(i);
  ItemsRepository.getInstance().update(items.get(i));
}
```

Sorry if my question was not detailed

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand to your question, you just need the index number and not the element value.

Then don't even consider using the element value rather reply on the index number.

Alternatively, delete the last index.